# android pass parameters with cloud function using volley

Tags: java, android

```
public void  getJsonResponsePost(String startDate,String endDate){
    ArrayList<String>currentStylistId=new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0;i<stylistidArray.size();i++){
        currentStylistId=stylistidArray.get(i);
    }
     try{
         for (currentStylistIdPostion=0;currentStylistIdPostion<=currentStylistId.size();currentStylistIdPostion++){
             String url=String.format("https://us-central1-meetdax2.cloudfunctions.net/freeBusyFlow12?startDate="+startDate+"&endDate="+endDate+"&currentStylistID="+currentStylistId.get(currentStylistIdPostion));
             BooleanRequest booleanRequest = new BooleanRequest(GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<Boolean>() {
                 @Override
                 public void onResponse(Boolean response) {
                     Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(response), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
             }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                     Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
             });
             // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
             requestQueue.add(booleanRequest);
         }

     }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Iam passing three parameters with cloud function startDate endDate and id.The startDate and endDate is timestamp and the id is string.I am having array of id i want to pass each id in array with same startdate and endDate so using for loop to pass parameters.Its giving server error the thing is id in array is not passing properly that why i am getting error.i had tried with postman with the same parameters its giving the response.so please suggest me some other method to pass parameters with an array.For example if array size is 4 i want to pass four times with same start and end date and also need to get four responses.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you must be getting crash because you are exceeding the list size during traversal here

```
currentStylistIdPostion<=currentStylistId.size()
```

instead use `<` not `<=`

```
for (currentStylistIdPostion=0;currentStylistIdPostion < currentStylistId.size();currentStylistIdPostion++){
```

And the purpose of `currentStylistId=stylistidArray.get(i);` is unclear.With loop, you are just assigning the last element of `stylistidArray` to `currentStylistId` list so

either you can use `currentStylistId=stylistidArray.get(stylistidArray.size()-1);` without for loop

or you want to use

```
for(int i=0;i<stylistidArray.size();i++){
    currentStylistId.addAll(stylistidArray.get(i));
}
```

Comment: i want to use for loop because stylistidArray is arrayOfarray List i want to store all values in stylistArray to currentStylistID then i have  to pass parameters with number of array size

Comment: also i tried with your suggestion it giving same server error

Comment: post the server errors and as suggested , read the answer again regarding for loop for optimised answer

Comment: currentStylistId=stylistidArray.get(stylistidArray.size()-1);
            for(currentStylistIdPostion=0;currentStylistIdPostion<currentStylistId.size();currentStylistIdPostion++){}

Comment: what is the error? and what is the purpose of above comment

Comment: I solved the issue its server error.Thanks for your response.

Comment: you should delete you post then